# Ionic text area value not a auto height

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 3 and I'm getting text area value in using database. I try to do large paragraph to set my text area height to auto but it is not working. It always overflows and thus adding a scroll. How do I do that correctly?

Here is my code

**html**

```
<div *ngIf="timeLineItems.get(postID)['POSTTYPE'] == '9'" [style.backgroundColor]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['TEXTTHEME']">
  <ion-textarea id="postBackground" [(ngModel)]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['MESSAGE']" readonly></ion-textarea>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#postBackground {
  width: calc(100%);
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;
}
```

my issue

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ion-textarea-resize-height-dynamically/80885

Comment: @RonNabuurs Sir ,I seen that. but that one is a someone enter after aut o height. my issue is im getting data in database. im not use keyinput

Comment: You want to make all the text visible, by resizing the text area based on the size of the text you are getting from the database. Is that what you are trying to achive?

Comment: @Karrthik yes sir. im all ready do that getting data part. but text area is not resize

Comment: @Karrthik look my attached image . you can understand it

Comment: You may have to use jquery for it.

Comment: @Karrthik Sir.   why cant do that in css. do you know how to do that in ionic

Comment: We can use jquery in ionic also. There is no limtation of using jquery in ionic. We need to import jquery library into ionic and we can use query directly. Please check the answer I have posted.

Comment: But if you are using a textarea that is readonly, why not use a standard `<div>` instead?

Comment: @RonNabuurs Thanks sir. finally i put the div tag now its work  `<div  id="postBackground"    [textContent]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['MESSAGE']"  ></div>`

Comment: I added the answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to display the text you can just use a `div` tag instead of a `ion-textarea` that is readonly.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Its work for now i changes some small things `<div  id="postBackground"    [textContent]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['MESSAGE']"  ></div>`

Answer (score 1):

add `(keypress)` to `ion-textarea` : `(keypress)="setHeight(this)`

```
<div *ngIf="timeLineItems.get(postID)['POSTTYPE'] == '9'" [style.backgroundColor]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['TEXTTHEME']">
  <ion-textarea id="postBackground" [(ngModel)]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['MESSAGE']" readonly (keypress)="setHeight(this)"></ion-textarea>
</div>
```

And in **TS** add function:

```
setHeight(this) {
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

**To your comment:**

> my issue is im getting data in database. im not use keyinput

when you get the data set in input and send to function you can get the element by his `class/id` instead using `this`
**For example:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
//get from db and set in input then:
 setHeight();
}
setHeight() {
   document.getElementByClassName('input').style.height =  document.getElementByClassName('input').scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
```

Comment: sir. im not going to input value is enter. im getting value for my data base

Answer (score 1):

Place this after the data is loaded into your text area

```
$("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed my issue.I got an idea's from @Ron Nabuurs.

`<div  id="postBackground"    [textContent]="timeLineItems.get(postID)['MESSAGE']"  ></div>`

I removed the text area and   replaced `[(ngModel)]` to  `[textContent]`